# Task share object - salesforce

Tags: salesforce

Do we have the TaskShare object or ActivityShare object in salesforce. Does anyone have any documentation on this?

Answer (score 4):

Activity data model is in the docs [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_erd_activities.htm) There's no TaskShare or ActivityShare because sharing on activities is controlled by the reference `Who` or `What` related object.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the data model! A picture is worth a thousand words.

Answer (score 0):

If your org has Shared Activities enabled then you will have access to the [TaskRelation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_taskrelation.htm#sforce_api_objects_taskrelation) object.